# Argmax on 2D GEE Array with more than 2 elements

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

How do you take `argmax` on a 2D `ee.Array` with more than 2 elements?

The result with just 2 elements works as expected (in Python API), as suggested by the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-array):

```
ee.Array([[3, 4, 2], [6, 5, 7]]).argmax().getInfo()  # [1, 2]
```

But when I try this with 3 elements or more, I still get a list of 2 and it looks like it is taking just the `argmax` of the last two elements:

```
ee.Array([[3, 4, 2], [6, 5, 7], [9, 8, 1]]).argmax().getInfo()  # [2, 0]
```

The expected result would be: `[1, 2, 0]`

Comment: Did you try argmax(array)? The argmax [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) suggests this syntax.

Comment: @Padmanabha I am using Google Earth Engine's array argmax function, not numpy

Comment: Sorry, got confused since you were using python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Argmax returns the corrdinates of the maximum element.
The array you're using is a 2D array, so you're getting the (2D) index of the maximum element in the array.  Expanding it out, you're using:

```
[[3, 4, 2]
 [6, 5, 7]
 [9, 8, 1]]
```

And the maximum value of that array is the 9, which is in row 2, column 0 (2,0). If you are hoping to use it over each "row" independently, you would need to convert the array to a list of lists and map over that:

```
print(ee.Array([[3, 4, 2], [6, 5, 7], [9, 8, 1]])
    .toList()
    .map(function(list) {
        return ee.Array(list).argmax()
    }))
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Looks like we arrived at the same answer, but I appreciate your explanation of the 'why'.

Answer (score 1):

This certainly isn't the most efficient, but this is how I managed to solve it:

```
array = ee.Array([[3, 4, 2], [6, 5, 7], [9, 8, 1]])
idx = array.toList().map(lambda i: ee.Array(i).argmax()).flatten()
idx.getInfo()  # [1, 2, 0]
```

I turn the array into a list so that I can use `map` and apply the `argmax` function to each element separately, which requires returning the element to an array and flattening the concatenated list.

Comment: GEE argmax may have limitations to calculate from 2D arrays. I think this is the ultimate solution. You can accept the answer, if you are satisfied.